# Can I declare an interface method to return generic Interface in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface

I am attempting to create a generic interface where one of its methods will return a T which could also be an Interface, is that possible in C#?

```
public interface IGetCard<T>
{
  T WithBoard<T>(string boardName);
}
```

And then, in order to implement this:

```
public class GetCard : IGetCard
{
  public IGetCard WithBoard<IGetCard>(string boardName)
  {
    // ...do stuff...
    return this;
  }
}
```

My intention is to Implement this interface method from various classes which implement that interface, e.g.:

```
public class DisplayCard : IDisplayCard, IGetCard
{
  public IDisplayCard WithBoard<IDisplayCard>(string boardName)
  {
    // ...do stuff...
    return this;
  }
}
```

What is the best alternative to achieve that?

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately your interface declares an open generic method and that's what you will have to implement in your class (you will have to keep the `<T>` part). If, instead, you want your class to implement a specific closed version of this interface you should make the interface generic so that you choose the `T` when declaring your class. So remove the `<T>` from your method declaration, and then choose the `T` when implementing it in the class.

Comment: Since I'm not entirely sure what you want here it is hard to leave a good answer. You seem to want to declare a generic `IGetCard<T>` interface, but also to return a non-generic variant from your classes, is this right?

Comment: " is that possible in C#?" Why not simply try it out?

Comment: The interface  `IGetCard` introduces ambiguity as uses the same generic type for interface and method (not sure it's something you'd like to achieve). Apart from that the implementations should return specific types (i.e. `GetCard` instead of `IGetCard`, etc) since the interface prescribes to do that by its generic method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could do that, like this:

```
public interface IGetCard<out TCard>
{
    TCard WithBoard(string boardName);
}

public class DisplayCard : IDisplayCard, IGetCard<IDisplayCard>
{
    public IDisplayCard WithBoard(string boardName)
    {
       // ...do stuff...
       return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just specify the generic argument in your class-definition:

```
public interface IGetCard<T>
{
    // be aware that I omitted the <T> from the signature, as T is 
    // already defined on the class-level
    T WithBoard(string boardName); 
}
public class GetCard : IGetCard<MyCard>
{
    public GetCard WithBoard(string boardName)
    {
        // ...do stuff...
        return this;
    }
}
```

Of course, as `IGetCard<MyCard>` and `IGetCard<YourCard>`  are completey different interfaces that don´t have *anything* in common, you can also implement both from your class:

```
public class DisplayCard : ICard<MyCard>, IGetCard<YourCard>
{
    public MyCard WithBoard(string boardName)
    {
        // ...do stuff...
        return ...;
    }
    public YourCard WithBoard(string boardName)
    {
        // ...do stuff...
        return ...;
    }
}
```